# Ninject Web Api - Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

Yes, I did try fixing with other suggestions from Stackoverflow question/answers.

1. What is strange is that I thought I had this fixed....
2. I had read about web api and mvc resolvers being different with ninject so i thought that i fixed this a week ago.
3. I did end up getting all the packages from nuget after deleting the existing packages , so perhaps Nuget messed things up?

Here is my error

```
    {
      "Message": "An error has occurred.",
      "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AssignmentController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
      "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
      "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
      "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "Error activating IGenericRepository{InternInterest}\r\nNo matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.\r\nActivation path:\r\n  3) Injection of dependency IGenericRepository{InternInterest} into parameter internInterestRepository of constructor of type UnitOfWork\r\n  2) Injection of dependency IUnitOfWork into parameter unitOfWork of constructor of type AssignmentController\r\n  1) Request for AssignmentController\r\n\r\nSuggestions:\r\n  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IGenericRepository{InternInterest}.\r\n  2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.\r\n  3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.\r\n  4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.\r\n  5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.\r\n",
        "ExceptionType": "Ninject.ActivationException",
        "StackTrace": "   at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve(IRequest request)\r\n   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent)\r\n   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Create>b__2(ITarget target)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()\r\n   at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Resolve>b__f(IBinding binding)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent)\r\n   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Create>b__2(ITarget target)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()\r\n   at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Resolve>b__f(IBinding binding)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Ninject.Web.WebApi.NinjectDependencyScope.GetService(Type serviceType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"
      }
    }
```

**URL**

`http://localhost/PublicHealth.Intern.Business.WebApi/api/assignment/GetAssignments`

**Part of Ninject**

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
   kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

**web api controller**

```
public class AssignmentController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _UnitOfWork;

    public AssignmentController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public List<Assignment> GetAssignments()
    {
        var result = _UnitOfWork.AssignmentsRepository.Get();
        return result;
    }

    //......
  }
```

Comment: You didn't register anything, so how should ninject know which implementation he should create for IUnitOfWork, which depends on IGenericRepository{InternInterest}

Comment: Can you show the code where you replace Web API's `IDependencyResolver` or its `IControllerActivator`?